# Laravel 8: Filter/show data on blade view with array saved on db

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I have a table called "products" which contains some data and a column called "category" with random category name. I have tried to query it on my blade view and the data are shown perfectly. Now I  have another table called "categories" which contains arrays of specified categories example: ["Book", "Shirt", etc..]

**ProductContoller.php**

```
public function index($subdomain) {

     //Table which has products data
     $products = DB::table('products')->get();

     //Table which has array saved data
     $categories = DB::table('categories')->get();

     return view('products.index', compact('products', 'categories'));
}
```

Now what I want to do is to filter products which match the categories specified on "categories" table and hide all the other products which doesn't match.

Please help, any suggestion will be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with something like this:

```php
$categories = ['Book', 'Shirt'];

Product::query()->whereHas('category', function (Builder $query) use ($categories): void {
    $query->whereIn('name', $categories);
})->get();
```

Using [Eloquent's **whereHas** function](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Or:

```
Product::all()->filter(function (Product $product) use ($categories): bool  {
    return in_array($product->category->name, $categories);
});
```

Using [Collection's **filter** function](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter)

Assuming you're using models and relations.